# Django logging - custom filter works for handler, but does not work for logger

Tags: python-logging

I have a custom filter like this:

proj/proj/log_utils/filters.py:

```
import logging

class OnlyThisSeverity(logging.Filter):
     def filter(self, record):
         print('levelname: {}'.format(record.levelname))
         return record.levelno == logging.INFO
```

And Django settings look like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',

        },        
    },
    'filters': {
        'only_this_severity': {
            '()': 'android_blend.log_utils.filters.OnlyThisSeverity',
        }
    },

    'loggers': {
        'my_app': {
            'handlers': ('console',),  # 'console'
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
            'filters': ['only_this_severity']
        },

    }
}
```

Inside `my_app/test.py`, I have a function like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
   logger.info('Reporting info......')
   logger.error('Reporting error......')
```

If my filter works correctly, I should see only `Reporting info` in the console, whereas I see both lines.
So the problem is that `only_this_severity` filter is ignored. 
However, if I move the `filters` inside the `console` handler definition, then I achieve my goal. What I am doing wrong ? I want the filter to work 
for the logger `my_app`, and not only on handler level.
My ultimate goal is to change the custom behavour of logging lib. That is, for handlers of level 'X', I want them to respect only records of level 'X', not 'X and higher'.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter seems to work correctly even with the filter added at logger level.

This is my current output:

```
levelname: INFO
Reporting info......
levelname: ERROR
```

This is showing how the code is reaching the filter in both log operations, but filtering the error record.

I think that the problem might be in the logger hierarchy. When you use your `test.py` as an imported module, you're not getting the `'my_app'` logger, but the `'my_app.test'` which does not exist.

When this happens, the core retrieves the root logger and 'propagates' the default configuration to a new logger called `'my_app.test'` including it on the log hierarchy. This logger doesn't have your filter engaged.

Try forcing to get `'my_app'` logger by passing its name:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')

def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
   logger.info('Reporting info......')
   logger.error('Reporting error......')
```

Or you can use the root logger to define your filters and then let the application create the hierarchy for you:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',

        },        
    },
    'filters': {
        'only_this_severity': {
            '()': 'android_blend.log_utils.filters.OnlyThisSeverity',
        }
    },

    'loggers': {
        'root': {
            'handlers': ('console',),  # 'console'
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['only_this_severity']
        },

    }
}
```

I personally like this method because allows to safely call

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in your modules in order to show (with the proper formatter) the module from which you are logging.

From https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/

> Best practice when instantiating loggers in a library is to only
>   create them using the `__name__` global variable: the logging module
>   creates a hierarchy of loggers using dot notation, so using `__name__`
>   ensures no name collisions.